# regex for any digits mandatory and two decimal points

Tags: regex

I would need your help to create a regex for an input mask that would validate an attribute with 1 or 2 decimal numbers.

Example of valid values:

```
1234.1 (number can be any digits long before "." but only 1 number after ".")
1234.12 (number can be any digits long before "." but only 2 number after ".")
```

Comment: There should be some number digits before the decimal point

Answer (score 2):

This is a regex you can use:

```
^\d+\.\d{1,2}$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gP4eZ2/1)

The `\d` shorthand class matches a digit, `+` makes sure we match 1 or more preceding pattern, and a dot must be escaped. The `{1,2}` [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) makes sure we only match 1 or 2 digits.

Comment: Did it solve your problem, or do you need more assistance? Please also add the language you are using as a tag to the question.

Comment: Heh almost a copy of my answer, but I got totally voted down and deleted my answer, but why does one want to escape dots? That was the difference in our posts

Comment: @MikaelPuusaari: If you do not escape a dot, it means you match any character but a newline. That is a rough mistake in regex world especially if validation is under consideration.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I always thought it was redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Digits, decimal point and one/two digits after:

```
^\d+\.\d{1,2}$
```